# Disjoint Set and Union Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, tree, union

A union-find structure is a data structure
supporting the following operations:
● find(x), which returns the representative of
node x, and
● union(x, y), which merges the sets containing x
and y into a single set.

Find(x) is having a time complexity of **O(n)** , so to improve this we are advisied to used concept of **Ranks**

i.e.
**the larger connected component eats up the smaller one**
Which improves  the time complexity to **O(logn)**
I could not understand How we are improving Time Complexity By merging  trees on their basics of Rank(Depth) , and How the O(logn) time complexity is achieved.
Please help me to Understand my concept of merging trees on the basis of their Rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to understand the maximal height of the tree representing the sets is of size `log(n) + 1`, thus, following up nodes from any given node to its root is done by `O(log(n))` steps.

We now have to prove the claim that each tree in the disjoint set forest is at most of height `log(n) + 1` - where `n` is the number of nodes in this tree. We will prove it by induction and show that after each `union(x,y)` - this property remains unchanged.

**Base**: When we begin, we have `n` different trees, all of size 1. `log(1) + 1 = 1` - so each tree is indeed of maximal height `log(n) + 1`

**Union(x,y)**: We unite two sets, `x` of size `n1` and y of size `n2`. Without loss of generality, let `n1<=n2`.

 From induction hypothesis, the height h1 of the tree representing `x` is at most `log(n2)+1`
So, the union operation is done by changing `x`'s root to point to `y`'s root. This means that the maximal height of any node that was in `x` is now at most

```
h1+1 = log(n1)+1 + 1 = log(n1) + log(2) + 1 = log(2*n1) + 1 = log(n1 + n1) + 1 <= log(n1 + n2) + 1
```

So, we have just found out that for every node that was formally in `x`, the maximal distance to the root is `log(n1+n2) + 1`, and the size of the new tree (`x` and `y` united) is now `n1+n2`, so we proved that the desired property remains for any node that was formally in `x`.

For `y` - the distance to root remains, while the size of the tree does not shrink - so the property is valid there too. 

In conclusion - for all node that was in `x` or `y`, the maximal depth from the new root is now `log(n1+n2)+1`, as required.

**QED**

---

remark - all `log` in this answer is with base 2.